# Mocking - Can a mock patch be toggled on/off selectively using start() stop()

Tags: mocking, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I'm charged with adding a unit test to an existing TestCase object. The setup method instantiates and starts several unittest.patch objects on functions that I need to test unmocked. Is calling `stop()` on the relevant patch before running my tests, then calling `patch.start()` on the same object a valid approach? Or would the patch have to be reinstantiated after calling `stop()`? Something like this:

```
class MyTestCase(unitites.TestCase):
    
    def setup(self):
        self.patch_to_toggle('some.module.Class.method', return='thisOrThat')
        self.patch_to_toggle.start()
        
    def test_toggle_patch(self):
        self.patch_to_toggle.stop()
        result = some.module.Class.method(*args)
        self.assertTrue(...)
        self.patch_to_toggle.start()
```

Comment: As long as you don't rely on the identity of the mock, this will work (each `start()` creates a new mock).